# Missing or insufficient permissions firestore although it works on rules play ground

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, firebase-security

I have added some security rules to my project and tested them in rules playground everything seems to be working perfect but when I try to retrieve the same doc using same UID from my website it throws error: "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions".

Refrence to collection:

`dbRef = db.collection("organization").doc(organization).collection(course).doc(courseId).collection("meetings");`

This are the snapshot of my code:

[image: function causing error]

[image: Updated security rules]

Note: I have already tested the security rules in rules playground with different uids and paths. And it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I am little new to this platform

Comment: Hi @rounak. It seems like you are not using the suggestion, please post your code as formatted text instead of using images. You can click the edit button below your post to do so. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how you can format your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

`dbRef = db.collection("organization").doc(organization).collection(course).doc(courseId).collection("meetings");`
This query attempts to fetch all documents under `meeting` collection.

There is a possibility that the above query will fetch documents where `designation != 'Teacher' && courseId != course`;

Therefore it will fail.

From [firestore rules docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules)

if you have this rule:

```
match /stories/{storyid} {
  // Only the authenticated user who authored the document can read or write
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
}
```

and this request `db.collection("stories").get()`.

> The query fails even if the current user actually is the author of every story document. The reason for this behavior is that when Cloud Firestore applies your security rules, it evaluates the query against its potential result set, not against the actual properties of documents in your database. If a query could potentially include documents that violate your security rules, the query will fail.

the following query succeeds, because it includes the same constraint on the author field as the security rules:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
db.collection("stories").where("author", "==", user.uid).get()
```

NB: playground can only test for document gets (not list collection).

**Possible solution.**
You can write your query in such a way that it can never return the wrong document.

Something like this. When a student is enrolled to take a meeting (or course), add his uid to that meeting's document.
`doc = {student_ids = [uidofstudent1, uidOfStudent2, ...]}`.

Then you can query like this:

```
db
    .collection("organization")
    .doc(organization)
    .collection(course)
    .doc(courseId)
    .collection("meetings")
    .where('student_ids', arrayContains: studentUid);
```

Your firestore rules can be something like this:

```
match /organisation/{org}/{course}/{courseId}/meetings/{meet=**} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.student_ids || 
    isTeacher(request.auth.uid);
}
```

Comment: actually that's not the real path i accidently removed some of the codes while taking snap shot. I  have edited the post please check out this code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, your new rules are okay. The problem might be from `isEnrolled() || isTeacher`. To be sure that the problem is not from there, do `allow read: if true;`. If it goes through, it means isEnrolled or isTeacher is returning false;

Comment: in rules playground I have checked using appropriate UID it is true.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think that should explain what goes wrong.

Comment: That is correct if both the conditions are incorrect document will not be fetched but as I have mentioned i Have checked with appropriate conditions and it works in my rules playground but it doesn't work on my function

Comment: If isTeacher == true then it works but it is not working for isEnrolled in my website's code ( it works in rules playground)

Comment: you cannot simulate a collection query on playground. What you can simulate is document get. So even if it getting the document works on playground, that does not mean it will work on the device.

Comment: yes that's what concerning me because it can fetch single document in meetings collection but i am not sure about whole collection

Comment: Exactly. Let me update my answer with how you can query such records.

Comment: I was trying to do the opposite of what you are doing but i got your point. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. My suggested solution is to make sure the query can't ever return the wrong docs, but should still allow enrolled students access.